# Why is my "CREATE INDEX CONCURRENTLY .." command blocked by a "SELECT FROM" query? (Postgres 9.6)

Tags: sql, postgresql, transactions, ddl, pg-stat-statements

I was running a migration to create an index, but the migration was blocked by another query. I resolved the problem after discovering that there was another query blocking my migrations; and after cancelling the blocking query, I was able to successfully run the migration.

(My server is using Postgres 9.6 on Linux)

Here is how I discovered that my migration was blocked:

```sql
SELECT
    activity.pid,
    activity.usename,
    activity.query,
    blocking.pid AS blocking_id,
    blocking.query AS blocking_query
FROM pg_stat_activity AS activity
JOIN pg_stat_activity AS blocking ON blocking.pid = ANY(pg_blocking_pids(activity.pid));
```

which returned the following result:

```
| pid | usename | query                                                                           | blocking_id | blocking_query                                                              |
|-----+---------+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------+-------------+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------|
| 123 | my_user | CREATE  INDEX CONCURRENTLY "idx_orders_on_widget_id" ON "orders"  ("widget_id") | 456         | SELECT  "customers".* FROM "customers" WHERE "customers"."id" = $1 LIMIT $2 |
```

How is it possible that my migration (the `CREATE INDEX CONCURRENTLY ..` query) was being blocked by the `SELECT .. FROM ..` query? Even if the process running the blocking query was in a zombie state, I don't understand how my index creation query can be blocked by a "SELECT .. FROM .." query.

Can anyone offer insights about how this is possible?

If it helps, here is my schema (simplified for this question):

**Orders**

`id`

`widget_id`

`customer_id` (FK to `Customers`)

**Customers**

`id`

`company_id` (FK to `Companies`)

**Companies**

`id`

Some additional notes:

- I discovered that the index was blocked about ~8 hours after I ran the migration.
- After killing the blocking query, I dropped the `idx_orders_on_widget_id` index and re-ran the migration to re-create the index.
- After re-running the migration a second time, the index creation was finished in ~10 mins
- The server is running on Linux with Postgres 9.6

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[The documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-createindex.html) says:

> PostgreSQL supports building indexes without locking out writes. This method is invoked by specifying the `CONCURRENTLY` option of `CREATE INDEX`. When this option is used, PostgreSQL must perform two scans of the table, **and in addition it must wait for all existing transactions that could potentially modify or use the index to terminate**.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, and referencing the docs :) It explains how a `SELECT .. FROM ..` query that is in a zombie state can block the index creation. But wouldn't the `SELECT .. FROM ..` query have to modify or use that index?
The blocking query that I found above is `SELECT  "customers".* FROM "customers" WHERE "customers"."id" = $1 LIMIT $2`, which doesn't seem to modify or use the new index, `widget_id` on the `orders` table. Or maybe I'm missing something?

Comment: It says "could potentially modify". Perhaps the next statement in the same transaction would try to access the index?

Comment: Ah, that's a good point, which explains the behavior. Is it also possible that the *previous* statement in the same transaction already tried accessing the index?

Then later on in the transaction, the process enters a zombie state during the `SELECT .. FROM ..` query. If so, would that mean the transaction is using the index?

Comment: PostgreSQL doesn't check. It just waits for the concurrent transactions to finish.